# Eclipse: Logcat logs disappear very quickly. How to save at run-time? And Increase window buffer size?

Tags: eclipse, android-logcat

I am taking android logs using Logcat in Eclipse. But, they disappear very quickly from the Logcat screen.

Is there a way to either:

1. increase the buffer size of the Logcat window, so that I can see the logs later on also as there would enough stored in the buffer?
2. Is there a way to save them to  file through Eclipse at run time?

Thanks, 
Sunny

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Windows->Preferences->Android->Logcat:

You can change the maximum number of logcat messages to buffer.

1. Haven't found an answer for part 2.

Comment: The answer for part is 2--> Click on the little Floppy-disk icon next to log message type dropdown chooser. But do select the log messages before, otherwise it'll just save nothing and you'll get a file of 0 bytes.

Comment: @Sunny - The answer was useful.Thanks :)